# WCF DataContractSerialzer xml to object incomplete results

Tags: wcf, datacontractserializer

I'm creating a wcf wrapper service that returns xml from another web service.
What I'm noticing is that not all the xml from the source is being serialized to my object.

Here's the source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<methodResponse>
    <requestId>234843080</requestId>
    <errorCode>0</errorCode>
    <errorText></errorText>
    <processingTime>00:00:00.234</processingTime>
    <results>
        <resultCode>0</resultCode>
        <resultText></resultText>
        <resultCount>1</resultCount>
        <totalResultCount>1</totalResultCount>
        <result>           
            <contactId>123</contactId>
            <sourceFolderId>3443</sourceFolderId>
            <contactState>4</contactState>
            <contactStateSortOrder>3</contactStateSortOrder>            
            <contactType>person</contactType>
            <displayName>Bond, James</displayName>            
            <office>unknown</office>
            <department></department>
            <changeDate></changeDate>
            <firstName>James</firstName>
            <middleName></middleName>
            <lastName>Bond</lastName>            
            <jobTitle>Spy</jobTitle>            
            <ape>
                <address type='Street' typeId='1' relationship='Business' relationshipId='1'>
                    <addressLine></addressLine>                    
                    <city></city>
                    <state></state>
                    <postalCode></postalCode>                                                            
                </address>
                <phone type='Phone' typeId='1' relationship='Business' relationshipId='1'>
                    <phoneNumber></phoneNumber>
                    <description/>
                    <formattedPhone></formattedPhone>
                </phone>         
            </ape>
        </result>
    </results>    
</methodResponse>
```

The wcf wrapper service:

```
  [DataContract(Name="methodResponse", Namespace = "")]
    public partial class methodResponse {

    [DataMember]
    public int errorCode {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string errorText {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string requestId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public methodResponseResults[] results
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public partial class methodResponseResults
{
    [DataMember]
    public string resultCode {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string resultText {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string resultCount {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string totalResultCount {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public methodResponseResultsResult[] result {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[DataContract(Namespace="")]
public partial class methodResponseResultsResult {

public string contactId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    public string displayName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}



  [ServiceContract]    
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class WcfWrapperService
    {

 public Response GetXml()
        {    
            string uri = ""; // uri to source web service

            var dataContractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(methodResponse));

                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(uri))
                {
                    var result = (methodResponse)dataContractSerializer.ReadObject(reader);
//result object looks like:    
                //result.errorCode = 0;
                //result.errorText = null;
                //result.requestId = 234843080;
                //result.results = methodResponseResults[0];
                }


    // return Response object
                }
        }
```

The errorCode, errorText, requestId values are there but no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out is that you are trying to de/serialize a contract which contains attributes. `DataContractSerializer` has a few restrictions, one of which is that it can only serialize/deserialize elements. In order to properly handle this Schema, you will need to use an `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 0):

Your not setting any values for the `Order` property on your `DataMember` attributes. This means that the elements will be processed in alphabetical order which is most likely NOT what you want. You must explicitly set `Order` to ensure it matches the schema of the documents you will process. You may also need to set `IsRequired = false` if there are any elements that may or not be in the instance document.